Kolmogorov complexity of Brownian motion
Given a 2 dimensional Brownian motion path $B\subset \mathbb{R}^2$, I am trying to show that for any oracle $A\subset\mathbb{N}$, there is a point $x \in B$ such that
$$\liminf_{r\to\infty}\frac{K_r^A(x)}{r}=2$$
where $K_r^A(x)$ denotes the Kolmogorov complexity of $x$ at precision $r$ (truncating the decimal expansion of $x$ at $r$ digits) given the oracle $A$. I honestly have no idea how to think about the complexity of points in this set, but intuitively it makes sense, as $(x,y) \in B$ should be pretty random, its complexity at precision $r$ should basically be $2r$. I am a little out of my depth, any help is appreciated.
Note: see survey by J. Lutz and N. Lutz for more info: arXiv link.

this sounds interesting, can you include in your posts the mathematical definitions (or at least links) for oracle $A$ and Kolmogorov complexity $K^{A}_{r}(x)$?

I think this survey does a nice job of explaining/motivating the ideas https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.00284

one guess is that is to show that in the case of BM, this dimension equals the Hausdorff dimension, which is known to be 2 in dimensions two and higher. For example, in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2007.14346, they mention such a result Corollary 3.4. for self-similar fractals (BM is too) that can be generated by an iterated function system, which I suppose is possible using the Levy construction of interpolating iid Gaussians. Here https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0601379 they discuss a bit on BM and IFS.
